# strange problem "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" when invoking other selenium-server maven project

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'm trying to run a Maven project(e.g. regking) which invoking other Maven project (e.g. selenium-geetest-crack) and the latter included selenium-server library configuration in pom.xml

regking's code is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new doubanSelenium().requestMobile();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

selenium-geetest-crack's about is :

```
public class doubanSelenium { 

    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    public String requestMobile() throws InterruptedException {
        ChromeOptions chrome_options = new ChromeOptions();
        chrome_options.setBinary("C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Yandex\\YandexBrowser\\Application\\browser.exe");
        ChromeDriver chrome_driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

the strange exception code is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean okio.ByteString.startsWith(okio.ByteString)'
    at okio.Options.of(Options.java:64)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:73)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnectionPool.<clinit>(RealConnectionPool.java:48)
    at okhttp3.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:40)
    at okhttp3.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:36)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient$Factory.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:142)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:591)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault(HttpClient.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<clinit>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:48)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:105)
```

selenium-geetest-crack's pom.xml about is :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.github.wycm</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-geetest-crack</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>selenium-geetest-crack</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Check the version of selenium you are using. Are you sure this method actually exist. That error occurs a lot when you upgrade versions and some method gets deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you don't have the right version of the selenium library. 
This is what happened to me in the past

Comment: thanks! solved after replace "selenium-server" with "selenium-java"